# Using useState hooks within an async callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm running an async operation with a callback (ipfs in this case, but it probably doesn't matter), and I'm trying to set state using hooks within that callback. But the code isn't operating...do I need to use useEffect here maybe?

```
await ipfs.add(buffer, (err, ipfsHash) => {
      setIpfsHash(ipfsHash);
      console.log("in ipfs - ipfshash", ipfsHash);
});
```

setIpfsHash is blocking the inner code. The console.log does not run

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproduce example on codesanbox.io https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can't see any problem with above code

Comment: what's not working? cool stuff for ipfs.

Comment: Are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0):

The way you're handling your `ipfs.add` function with `async/await` is incorrect. But yes, you'd want to use `React.useEffect` in this situation.

If you want to use `async/await`, you need to create a new promise. In your example, `ifps.add(buffer, callback)` looks it's taking a callback as an argument, so this won't work.

Instead, turn it into a promise:

```js
function add(buffer) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const ipfs = ...

    ipfs.add(buffer, (error, ipfsHash) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error)
        return
      }
      resolve(ipfsHash)
    })
  })
}
```

Then, you can use `async/await` in your `React.useEffect` like in the following example:

```js
function App() {
  const [buffer, setBuffer] = React.useState(null)
  const [ipfsHash, setIpfsHash] = React.useState(null)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function doWork() {
      try {
        const result = await add(buffer)
        setIpfsHash(result)
      } catch (error) {
        // handle error
      }
    }
    doWork()
  }, [buffer])

  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

Make sure to specify a dependency array for your `useEffect` hook so that it only runs when it needs to:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  // ...
}, [buffer])
```